# How would you make an Excel-like user interface with Django?

Tags: python, django, excel

I am currently working on a project where the user wants the user interface to look like an Excel document. This is because the user normally writes data into an Excel document, and wants to switch to writing data straight into the user-interface instead. It should look something like this:

[image]

In this project, so far, I have only used Django, and there was no need for using Bootstrap, for example. However, I would be willing to use a front-end framework in order to create this Exel-like user interface. Trying to make html-tables have been unsuccessful so far.

Does anyone have suggestions on how it might be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps best thing to do first is to convince someone that the UI doesn't have to be like Excel.

Definitely worth consider `gspread` so that you don't get stuck in a complex relational structure.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vISRn5qFrkM and https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply! :D We are now considering your option, it actually seems easier then making an Excel-like UI. It turned out doing that was way more complicated then it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Django is basically for developing webapp .

1. You have to create model(default db) and then store your data there .
2. You should create a webapp and one of the html page should have the above tables and you should give your model data as input to your html page using django views

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply Sandeep!